# How to execute different functions in same script by clicking different buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a button inside my form as below,

```
<form method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3">
              <button  type='button'  id ="btnnew" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
              <p></p>
        </div>
</form>
```

So my script as below, from that I will run me `testme.php`.

```
 $("#btnnew").confirm({
      
      title: "Confirmation",
      text: "Do you really need?",
      confirm: function(button) {        
        console.log('AJAX request in progress...');
        
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'testme.php',
          success: function(data) {
            $("p").text(data);
          },
          complete: function() {      
            $('#loading').hide();
          }
        });
        
      },
      cancel: function(button) {
        console.log("You aborted the operation.");
      },
      confirmButton: "Yes I Need",
      cancelButton: "No"
    });
```

My `testme.php` as follows,

```
<?php
sleep(5);
echo 'Hi Done';

?>
```

This works fine..Now I need to do this same approach to many buttons..only different is the button id and the runnning script only... As an example,

```
<form method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3">
              <button  type='button'  id ="btnnew" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
              <p></p>
        </div>
         <div class="mb-3">
              <button  type='button'  id ="btnnew2" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
              <p></p>
         </div>
         <div class="mb-3">
              <button  type='button'  id ="btnnew3" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
              <p></p>
         </div>
</form>
```

But I need to change the function from my `testme.php` as well as below,

```
if btnnew clicks
    sleep(5);
    echo 'Hi Done button1';

if btnnew2 clicks
    sleep(10);
    echo 'Hi Done button2';

if btnnew3 clicks
    sleep(15);
    echo 'Hi Done button3';
```

Can I do this task by using only one script?

Comment: As an `id` is **not** sent in a form submission ( only the `name` is! ) you could use Javascript to send an ajax request with the ID which is processed in PHP to trigger whichever function you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a basic example of how you might accomplish the stated objective of triggering different pieces of PHP code dependent upon which button is clicked in the browser perhaps the following might be of help.

The javascript binds a `click` event handler to each button which sends the ID if the `event.target` (button ) within an ajax request.

The PHP script processes the `$_POST['bttn']` variable and uses a simple `switch` to fork the program logic

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['bttn'] ) ){
        switch( $_POST['bttn'] ){
            case 'btnnew':
                sleep(5);
                exit( 'Hi Done button1' );
            break;
            case 'btnnew2':
                sleep(10);
                exit( 'Hi Done button2' );
            break;
            case 'btnnew3':
                sleep(15);
                exit( 'Hi Done button3' );
            break;
            default:
                exit('Bad Foo!');
            break;
        }
        
    }
?>



<form method="POST">
    <div class="mb-3">
          <button  type='button' id="btnnew" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
          <p></p>
    </div>
     <div class="mb-3">
          <button  type='button' id="btnnew2" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
          <p></p>
     </div>
     <div class="mb-3">
          <button  type='button' id="btnnew3" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
          <p></p>
     </div>
</form>

<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        let fd=new FormData();
            fd.set('bttn', this.id );
        
        fetch( location.href, { method:'post', body:fd })
            .then(r=>r.text())
            .then(text=>alert(text))            
    }))
</script>
```

---

As I do not use jQuery at all and cannot find reference to the `.confirm` method I can offer no advice on it. However using vanilla Javascript and some additional code it is possible to popup a dialog to serve your needs as I understand them.

The following snippet uses a class I wrote a while ago to interact with a HTML `dialog` element. The callbacks are assigned to the buttons and if the `Accept` button is clicked the callback will fire an ajax request with the button ID that invoked the dialog. ( use the console to inspect the network traffic )

```js
const url = 'testme.php';

let modal;
let fd = new FormData();

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(bttn => bttn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  fd.set('bttn', this.id);

  let dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
  let content = document.querySelector('template').content.cloneNode(true);
  content.querySelector('h4').textContent = `You clicked: ${fd.get('bttn')}`;

  let attr = {
    width: '200px',
    height: '250px'
  };

  let callbacks = {
    'accept': {
      type: 'click',
      callback: acceptcallback
    },
    'reject': {
      type: 'click',
      callback: rejectcallback
    }
  };

  modal = new Modal(dialog, content, attr, callbacks).open();
}));

const acceptcallback = (e) => {
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      body: fd
    })
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(text => alert(text))
};
const rejectcallback = (e) => {
  alert("I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.\n\nLook Dave, I can see you're really upset about this. I honestly think you ought to sit down calmly, take a stress pill, and think things over.");
  modal.close();
};











class Modal {
  constructor(dialog = false, content = false, attr = {}, callbacks = {}) {
    this.dialog = dialog;
    this.callbacks = callbacks;
    this.content = content;
    this.attr = attr;
    return this.create();
  };

  create() {
    this.dialog.innerHTML = '';

    if (this.content.nodeType == 1 || this.content.nodeType == 11) this.dialog.append(this.content);
    else this.dialog.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.content)

    this.setattributes();
    this.bindEvents();

    return this;
  };

  setattributes() {
    let exceptions = ['innerHTML', 'innerText', 'html', 'text', 'textContent', 'width', 'height'];
    Object.keys(this.attr).forEach(k => {
      if (!exceptions.includes(k)) this.dialog.setAttribute(k, this.attr[k]);
    });
    if (this.attr.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') || this.attr.hasOwnProperty('html')) this.dialog.innerHTML = this.attr.innerHTML || this.attr.html;
    if (this.attr.hasOwnProperty('innerText') || this.attr.hasOwnProperty('text') || this.attr.hasOwnProperty('textContent')) this.dialog.textContent = this.attr.innerText || this.attr.text || this.attr.textContent;
    if (this.attr.hasOwnProperty('width')) this.dialog.style.width = this.attr.width;
    if (this.attr.hasOwnProperty('height')) this.dialog.style.height = this.attr.height;
  };

  checkstyle(n, p) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(n).getPropertyValue(p)
  };
  setstyle(n, p, v) {
    n.style[p] = v
  };

  setposition() {
    if (!this.dialog.showModal) {
      let r = 10;
      let dw = parseInt(this.checkstyle(this.dialog, 'width'), r);
      let dh = parseInt(this.checkstyle(this.dialog, 'height'), r);
      let sw = screen.availWidth;
      let sh = screen.availHeight;

      let px = (sw - dw) / 2;
      let py = (sh - dh) / 2;

      this.setstyle(this.dialog, 'position.top', py + 'px');
      this.setstyle(this.dialog, 'position.left', px + 'px');
      this.setstyle(this.dialog, 'z-index', 100);
    }
  };

  bindEvents() {
    if (this.callbacks && Object.keys(this.callbacks).length > 0) {
      Object.keys(this.callbacks).forEach(key => {

        let node = this.dialog.querySelector('[data-handler="' + key + '"]');
        let type = this.callbacks[key].hasOwnProperty('type') ? this.callbacks[key].type : 'click';
        if (node && node.nodeType == 1) {
          node.addEventListener(type, this.callbacks[key].callback);
        }
      })
    }
  };

  open() {
    if (this.dialog.showModal) this.dialog.showModal();
    else this.dialog.setAttribute('open', true);

    this.setposition();

    return this;
  };
  close() {
    this.dialog.innerHTML = '';
    [...this.dialog.attributes].forEach(attr => {
      if (attr.name != 'open') this.dialog.removeAttribute(attr.name);
    });

    if (this.dialog.close) this.dialog.close();
    else this.dialog.removeAttribute('open');

    return this;
  };
};
```

```css
::backdrop{
  background:black;
  background-image:url(https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX17560307.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <button type='button' id="btnnew" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <button type='button' id="btnnew2" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <button type='button' id="btnnew3" class="btn btn-info">submit</button>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</form>


<dialog></dialog>

<template>
  <h4></h4>
  <p>Are you really sure you want to do that Dave?</p>
  <p>This mission is too important for me to allow you to jeopardize it.</p>
  <input type='button' name='accept' value='Accept' data-handler='accept' />
  <input type='button' name='reject' value='Reject' data-handler='reject' />
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks!!.. Is there any change in my existing ajax function to pop up the window and getting the confirmation? Becuase now I have several buttons not only the mentioned one.

Comment: This didnt worked for me

Comment: What about the ajax button? As OP he has the php code in separate file. not in the same one..

Comment: The `fetch` request could easily be directed to another script (testme.php etc).

Comment: `"Is there any change in my existing ajax function to pop up the window"` - I don't use jQuery so am unfamiliar with what that function is doing. But it should be easy enough to adapt the event listener above to incorporate your jQuery logic of popup/alert

Comment: I need the ajax function as well and the php code should be in different file, not in the same one...

Comment: Your code yields an error for me when I tested i and I have no idea whether jQuery has a `confirm` method as suggested here nor how it should be used. The PHP code **can easily** be a different script rather than the single page shown here - where `location.href` is used replace with your script `'testme.php'`

Comment: Now this worked... I have marked it as accepted...I will check to include jquery popup as well..

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius could you please update your answer with a confirmation box as well? Need a text and yes ,no functions. if someone clicked yes,,need to execute the testme.php