# How to call different PHP functions in same file with buttons

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a separated php file with some functions.. I need to call each one when I click a button..

Here is my testme.php

```
    <?php
    
//when button1 clicks
    sleep(5)
    echo 'Hi, you have clicked button 1'
    
//when button2 clicks
    sleep(8)
    echo 'Hi, you have clicked button 2'

    
    ?>
```

From this link I have found some examples,https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Confirm-Dialog-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Confirm/ and implemented some confirm dialog boxes as below,

```
<form method="POST">
<div class="mb-3">
   <button  type='button'  id ="btnnew2" class="btn btn-info">Get Latest Graph</button>
    <p></p>
</div>
</form>
```

The script as below,

```
$("#btn1").confirm({
  
  title: "Confirmation",
  text: "Are you sure?",
  confirm: function(button) {        
    console.log('AJAX request in progress...');
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'testme.php',
      success: function(data) {
        $("p").text(data);
      },
      complete: function() {      
        $('#loading').hide();
      }
    });
    
  },
  cancel: function(button) {
    console.log("You aborted the operation.");
  },
  confirmButton: "Yes I Need",
  cancelButton: "No"
});
```

How should I use this same approach when I have many buttons like below?

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="mb-3">
       <button  type='button'  id ="btn1" class="btn btn-info">Get Latest Graph</button>
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
       <button  type='button'  id ="btn2" class="btn btn-info">Get Latest Graph</button>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Note: Answers can be found in here [How to execute different functions in same script by clicking different buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72667475/how-to-execute-different-functions-in-same-script-by-clicking-different-buttons/72667553#72667553) , but I would like this to do with above method, since less coding..

---

Update:

Seems the requirement is unclear. Sorry for that. Let me start from the beginning. I have a button and when the button clicks it popups for confirmation when user confirmed the testme.php is running. Here is the testme.php contains..

```
 <?php       
    //when button1 clicks
        sleep(5)
        echo 'Hi, you have clicked button 1'
        
  ?>
```

The button is as follows,

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="mb-3">
       <button  type='button'  id ="btn1" class="btn btn-info">Get Latest Graph</button>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    </form>
```

and the jquery function is as follows,

```
$("#btn1").confirm({
      
      title: "Confirmation",
      text: "Are you sure?",
      confirm: function(button) {        
        console.log('AJAX request in progress...');
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'testme.php',
          success: function(data) {
            $("p").text(data);
          },
          complete: function() {      
            $('#loading').hide();
          }
        });
        
      },
      cancel: function(button) {
        console.log("You aborted the operation.");
      },
      confirmButton: "Yes I Need",
      cancelButton: "No"
    });
```

Now the requirement is if I am having set of buttons, lets say button1,button2; how should I change my `testme.php` file to run according to the button click..

```
<?php
        
    //when button1 clicks
        sleep(5)
        echo 'Hi, you have clicked button 1'
        
    //when button2 clicks
        sleep(8)
        echo 'Hi, you have clicked button 2'
    
        
        ?>
```

The last post answer do not use the method which I use here and its too much coding there.

Here are my plugins

```
<script>src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sliding-Confirm-Dialog-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Confirm/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Please clarify what the difference with the above method is to what that post suggests. If that post contains a solution, what with it is it you don't want (and why, since that could answer potential XY problems)? We don't want to waste time comparing both examples just to assuming the wrong thing. Always make it as easy for us to answer as possible.

Comment: Already mentioned the reasons...Too much coding there and I need to implement a method using my existing code which I developed for only one button...

Comment: Ok, so that's the _why_ (which most likely are based on assumptions since you don't have a proof of concept yet)... but you still need to clarify the _what_? Like I said, don't require us to read up on both just to end up assuming the wrong thing. What _exactly_ is the difference and the question here? We need _specifics_.

Comment: “but I would like this to do with above method” - What above? The PHP which is just 4 lines? Or something about the jQuery?

Comment: I have updated the question now. Hope now that is clear..

Comment: What confirm plugin are you using? Explore `button`, I suspect it has `.target.*` on it which you can find out clicked button id from it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone updated plugins as well..

Comment: To be very clear, you know how to get the code to do what you want it to (based on your previous question), right? You are looking for a more efficient way to do it, and you are measuring efficiency in amount of code. Are both of these statements correct? If, it seems like you need a data layer, such as a database, that describes your conditions. Also, you need to focus this more. Is this a “button problem”, and then therefor HTML/jQuery, or a server-side problem, thus PHP and HTTP. It is very rare to be both, and I’m not seeing a reason here

Answer (score 0):

There are many problem in your flow.
First call the ajax on btn class instead of btn id.
now you have to pass the id of clicked button to the php using ajax.

```
type: 'POST',
url: 'testme.php',
data :{id : $(this).attr(id) }
```

It will pass the id of clicked button to the testme.php

now in testme.php

```
id = $_POST['id']
```

add logic to use function according to id you get using if else.